# Android: Geocoder succeed on 3G, but fails on WiFi

Tags: android, geolocation, wifi, 3g

I am trying to retrieve address from location name like that:

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {
   addresses = gc.getFromLocationName("Dalvik, Iceland", 1);
} catch (IOException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

It works fine on 3G connection, but fails when i connected to WiFi access point. (of course, WiFi provides internet, and it works in another applications)

Stack trace:

```
02-20 00:06:42.410: W/System.err(25061): java.io.IOException: RPC failed with status 1
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at ru.dfrank.study.ecomobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:101)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
02-20 00:06:42.420: W/System.err(25061):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I use API level 7.
I googled and searched in stackoverflow.com very much, but still can't find the answer.

Any help appreciated.